# How to merge config files interactively after "yum update"

Tags: fedora, rhel, yum, rpm, etc

After system packages are updated with "yum update", config files which could not be overwritten are not replaced, but we can find *.rpmnew files near by. By design system administrator must merge config files.

In Gentoo Linux there is a [etc-update tool](https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=3&chap=4#doc_chap2), which allow to merge config file changes interactively, like that:

```
Beginning of differences between /etc/pear.conf and /etc/._cfg0000_pear.conf
[...]
End of differences between /etc/pear.conf and /etc/._cfg0000_pear.conf
1) Replace original with update
2) Delete update, keeping original as is
3) Interactively merge original with update
4) Show differences again
```

I wonder if there is a way to merge configs interactively in RHEL/Fedora/CentOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This yum plugin adds the "--merge-conf" command line option. With this
>   option, Yum will ask you what to do with config files which have
>   changed on updating a package.

https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/yum-plugin-merge-conf

Comment: afaik, this is outdated.

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing I've found to Gentoo's `etc-update` is [rpmconf](https://github.com/xsuchy/rpmconf/wiki):

```
# yum install -y rpmconf    
# rpmconf -a
Configuration file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-5.b18.fc21.x86_64/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar'
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 620 Oct  2 16:38 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-5.b18.fc21.x86_64/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 620 Dec 15 12:11 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.25-5.b18.fc21.x86_64/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar.rpmnew
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      M     : merge configuration files
      Z     : background this process to examine the situation
      S     : skip this file
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** aliases (Y/I/N/O/D/Z/S) [default=N] ? 
Your choice: Y
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way I found so far is vimdiff:

[image: vmdiff window with differing lines highlighted]